# How to get my element data outside cy for event

Tags: javascript, qtip, cytoscape.js

How to access element node data outside cy function? and here is my code :

```
function cytoFunc(myJson){
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
       // style
       // elements
}); // end of cy

cy.$('node').qtip({
  content: 'I want to insert element data here',
  position: {
    my: 'left center',
    at: 'bottom center'
  },
  style: {
    classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
    tip: {
      width: 16,
      height: 8
    }
  }
}); // end of cy.qtip
```

} // end of cytofunc

Comment: What element are you talking about?

Comment: elements: {
    nodes: [
      { data: { id: 'a', name: 'A' } },
      { data: { id: 'b', name: 'B' } },
      { data: { id: 'c', name: 'C' } },
      { data: { id: 'd', name: 'D' } }
    ]
  },

Answer (score 0):

Call qtip on each element if you want per-element granularity.  Use `.forEach()`.